# Comment dire « two-way mirror » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Je suis francais et je cherche comment on dit un « *two way mirror* », comme celui qui apparait dans [cette vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdRbt4NpewM), en français.

Comment: Un *two way mirror* est l'un de ces miroirs qui est un miroir d'un côté et un panneau transparent de l'autre, qui permet l'observation d'une pièce, par exemple dans un poste de police. Ce n'est pas ce dont il est question ici, pas vrai? Seulement ce téléviseur qui devient un miroir quand il est éteint (ce que je n'avais jamais vu, d'ailleurs)?

Comment: Mais c'est possible que le même principe soit utilisé...

Comment: Très facile à trouver: http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/two-way+mirror.html.  Oui @Kareen même terme - si je ne me tromper pas.

Comment: @Kareen c'est exactement le même principe. Il suffit d'ajouter une source lumineuse du côté "sombre" pour que le miroir n'en soit plus un.

Answer (score 8):

**miroir sans tain** ou [**glace sans tain**](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/glace_sans_tain)

Answer (score 0):

Un *two-way mirror* est en fait un [*one-way mirror*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror), et en terme technique un [`miroir semi-transparent`](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miroir_semi-r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chissant) (synonyme: semi-réfléchissant).

On dit communément une `glace sans tain` car la réflexion n'est pas obtenue par un tain (sel d'argent ou d'aluminium déposé derrière la lame de verre ou de [plexiglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(methyl_methacrylate)) et qui la transforme en miroir total) mais:

- par l'opacification de la lame, ou
- par l'application d'un [film plastique métallisé](https://www.hydrozone.fr/revetement-mylar/1586-film-mylar-rouleau-10-metres.html) à l'avant de la lame, ou
- par un système optique (prismes), ou même
- par une simple lame inclinée dans les [prompteurs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompteur).

Pour les miroirs semi-transparents courants, [tels que les lunettes de soleil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCJN35Y), les vitres de ["retapissage"](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/53053) des commissariats, le vitrage des [immeubles commerciaux](https://www.interglasssolutions.com/verre-reflechissant), etc, l'effet miroir est facilité par la différence d'intensité de l'éclairage de part et d'autre du verre et il disparait en grande partie dès qu'on équilibre les éclairages (à la tombée de la nuit, les vitrages des immeubles de bureaux deviennent transparents).

Le tain était à l'origine un amalgame d'étain (d'où le nom), une formule tenue secrète par les verriers Vénitiens qui avaient le monopole de la fabrication des miroirs en Europe. Louis XIV fit voler la formule pour fabriquer les miroirs géants de la [galerie des Glaces](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerie_des_Glaces) du château de Versailles à la [manufacture royale de La Glacerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacture_royale_de_glaces_de_miroirs) qui deviendra plus tard [Saint Gobain](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Gobain) et aura le succès que l'on sait.